# I need to reposition the squares when I put the mouse over JavaScript. How do I do that?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, css-animations

> A.Add in the "init" function the code required for the "reposition" function to be called as soon as you hover over an element of the page associated with the CSS class "square".
> B.Modify the "reposition" function so that it allows you to reposition the square in symmetry with respect to the diagonal.
> To do this, simply reverse the horizontal and vertical positions of this square.                 Note : the pink square will not move because it is precisely on the diagonal (identical horizontal and vertical positions).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Reposition the squares</title>
    <style>
        #bac {
            position: relative;
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .square {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        #square1 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 300px;
            top: 200px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        #square2 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 120px;
            top: 75px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
        #square3 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50px;
            top: 240px;
            background-color: orange;
        }
        #square4 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 350px;
            top: 0px;
            background-color: black;
        }
        #square5 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50px;
            top: 50px;
            background-color: pink;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function init() {
        //Code here

        }


        function reposition() {
        //code here
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <h1>Reposition the squares</h1>
    <div id="bac">
        <div id="square1" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square2" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square3" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square4" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square5" class="square"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use this script

```
<script>
    const squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
    for(let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
        squares[i].addEventListener("mouseover",(e)=>{
            let v = getComputedStyle(squares[i]);
            let top = v.getPropertyValue('top').replace(/\D/g, "");
            let left = v.getPropertyValue('left').replace(/\D/g, "");;
            if(top == left){
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else{
                squares[i].style.top = left+"px";
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

First I called all the squares then I made an event for each one of its

Second I've searched for top and left properties when I put the mouse over its

Third I got just the numbers from properties without "px", the reason why I used the Regex

Finally I gave the same top and left value for each square that they don't match

maybe someone can give you a short code but this is my solution (I'm still student), and it works for me.

Notice: the orange square will hide under the pink square because the both will have the same top and left value.

Comment: Thanks for the code.  Not sure in which function should I put it in. I have to 2 function to code.

Comment: it worked for me without functions but if you want to put it in a function to have to remove and modify something in my code, but I think I gave you an idea about how you can do it, good luck

Comment: I been trying to do it. Not able to could you show me how?